# Why the result is not the same, f Interpolator in scala

Tags: scala

```
val bb =0
val cc ="%07d"

println(f"$bb$cc")  //0%07d

println(f"$bb%07d") //0000000
```

I expect

println(f"$bb$cc") //0000000

println(f"$bb%07d") //0000000

Why isn't the result the same?
How can I make it the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using f"string" you are declaring that you want to make a formatted string.

with f"$bb$cc" you are using the variables bb and cc, so it accesses the strings for them

with f"$bb%07d" you are telling it to transform bb into a number with 7 decimal places, and 0s if the number isn't large enough

further examples to help understanding:

```
val bb = 1

println(f"$bb%07d") // 0000001

println(f"$bb%05d") // 00001

val bb = 11

println(f"$bb%05d") //00011
```

to get the same string, try using s"string"

```
val bb = 0
println(s"$bb%07d") // 0%07d
```

to use a string as a formatter:

```
val cc = "%07d"
val bb = 0
println(cc.format(bb)) //0000000
```

//for more information http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: How can I make it the same?

Comment: I expect

println(f"$bb$cc") //0000000

println(f"$bb%07d") //0000000

Comment: How can you make it the same?  As you can see from @JamesTobin's answer, this command `"%07d" format bb` and this command `cc format bb` give the same result.

Comment: @jwvh `format` throws at runtime. The whole point of exploiting the f-interpolator (besides syntax) is to validate the format at compile time. That's huge.

Comment: Isn't string interpolation handled by a macro at compile time? If so, you can't change the formatting rules at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you already know that, but just to be clear:

`$` is used for marking of variable references

`%` is used for formatting the references

Generally you use f interpolator like this: `f"$<reference>%<format>"`

*When you write:*

```
println(f"$bb$cc")
```

This is what happens:

1. Parser recognizes `$bb` with no formatting.
2. Parser recognizes `$cc` with no formatting.
3. Substitutes `$bb` with `0`
4. Substitutes `$bb` with `"%07d"`

*But when you write:*

```
println(f"$bb%07d")
```

This is what happens:

1. Parser recognizes `$bb` with formatting `07d`
2. Substitutes `$bb` with `0` and formats it according to `"07d"`, that is: 7 digits and filling with 0 is number is shorter than 7 digits.

*You might have thought of this method as being preprocessing like `#define cc "%07d"` in C but it's simply not.*

I'm not currently aware of a way to store the formatting in a separate string. You might consider using a class-based formatter for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation syntax requires a string literal.

The point of the f-interpolator macro is to give compile-time safety.

```
scala> val x = 0.1
x: Double = 0.1

scala> f"$x"
res0: String = 0.1

scala> f"$x%5.5f"
res1: String = 0.10000

scala> f"$x%5d"
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Int
       f"$x%5d"
          ^

scala> val fmt = "%5d"
fmt: String = %5d

scala> fmt format x
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.format(StringLike.scala:318)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.format(StringOps.scala:29)
  ... 32 elided
```

This isn't convenient, but you can decompose the string constants and roll it by hand:

```
scala> final val fmt = "%5d"
fmt: String("%5d") = %5d

scala> new StringContext("", fmt).f(x)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Int
       new StringContext("", fmt).f(x)
                                    ^
```

or

```
scala> final val fmt = "%5.5f"
fmt: String("%5.5f") = %5.5f

scala> new StringContext("", fmt).f(x)
res8: String = 0.10000

scala> final val fmt = "%5.5"
fmt: String("%5.5") = %5.5

scala> new StringContext("", fmt + "f").f(x)
res9: String = 0.10000

scala> new StringContext("", fmt + "d").f(x)
<console>:14: error: precision not allowed
       new StringContext("", fmt + "d").f(x)
                                   ^

scala> final val fmt = "%5"
fmt: String("%5") = %5

scala> new StringContext("", fmt + "d").f(x)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Int
       new StringContext("", fmt + "d").f(x)
                                          ^
```

The error if you try it with non-constant String:

```
scala> val fmt = "%5d"
fmt: String = %5d

scala> new StringContext("", fmt).f(x)
<console>:14: error: exception during macro expansion:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: internal error: argument parts must be a list of string literals
    at scala.tools.reflect.FormatInterpolator.scala$tools$reflect$FormatInterpolator$$copyPart$1(FormatInterpolator.scala:82)
    at scala.tools.reflect.FormatInterpolator.interpolated(FormatInterpolator.scala:181)
    at scala.tools.reflect.FormatInterpolator.interpolate(FormatInterpolator.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.apply(FastTrack.scala:54)
    at scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.apply(FastTrack.scala:54)
    at scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack$FastTrackEntry.apply(FastTrack.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack$FastTrackEntry.apply(FastTrack.scala:36)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$class.macroExpandWithRuntime(Macros.scala:763)

       new StringContext("", fmt).f(x)
                                   ^
```